# how to solve the indexing in java programming language

Tags: java

```
public static int indexOf(String text , char index){

        char array [] = new char[text.length()];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < text.length(); i++){
            array[i] = text.charAt(i);
        }// end of first loop
        // the above loop converts the string obj to char array

        for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++){
            if(array[i] == index){ // if a given letter is exist in string 
                System.out.println("The index of " + index + " is " + i);
                return i; // show or return the index of that given letter
            }
        }//end of second loop 
        System.out.println("The Letter you Entered does not Exist");
        return -1;
    }// end of method
```

this piece of code is for finding the index of string ;
first it takes a string and a character as an input than it convert it to array of characters than it search for an given lettter if it finds it.
method will return it's index but the main problem is that we have more than one same letter in a string so  it will return the first one .
and how could i detect the second one or how I can differentiate the second same  letter and show it is index for example:

indexOf("kingJoker",'k');

here in kingjoker  string we have two k letter the method can't find second k index so that is the problem.

Comment: Hashmap of counts?

Comment: Do you always want the index of last letter or all indexes of matching letter?

Comment: return will break out of the loop. Once your code finds the first letter matching, it will stop searching. What is your expected output?

Comment: BTW, there is no reason to have two `for` loops and `array` object. Just move all logic into the first loop.

Comment: thank you , i got my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Change the return type of your method to `int[]`
- Walk the string once to count the matches
- Make an array of the size equal to the count
- Walk the string again, populating the return indexes as you go.

Here is your modified implementation:

```
public static int[] indexesOf(String text , char ch) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i != text.length() ; i++) {
        if (text.charAt(i) == ch) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    int[] indexes = new int[count];
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i != text.length() ; i++) {
        if (text.charAt(i) == ch) {
            System.out.println("Found '" + ch + "' at " + i);
            indexes[pos++] = i;
        }
    }
    return indexes;
}
```

Comment: @Maseeh.Niazai You are welcome. Don't forget to accept one of the answers by clicking the check mark next to it. This would let other site visitors know that your problem is solved.

Comment: ok i got it thank you again and how can answer problems in stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

To detect multiple letters, I recommend you store every index within a `List<Integer>`.  You can use the following (courtesy of [smac89's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48592303/7294647)):

```
public static List<Integer> indexOf(String text, char index) {
    return IntStream.range(0, text.length())
                    .filter(i -> s.charAt(i) == index)
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```