# Java 8/9: Can a character in a String be mapped to its indices (using streams)?

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream, java-9

Given a `String s` and a `char c`, I'm curious if there exists some method of producing a `List<Integer> list` from `s` (where the elements within `list` represent the indices of `c` within `s`).

A close, but **incorrect** approach would be:

```
public static List<Integer> getIndexList(String s, char c) {
    return s.chars()
            .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
            .filter(ch -> ch == c)
            .map(s::indexOf) // Will obviously return the first index every time.
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The following inputs should yield the following output:

```
getIndexList("Hello world!", 'l') -> [2, 3, 9]
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:java-8] and [tag:java-9]. Which are you using?

Comment: @shmosel The tags are somewhat for exposure, as well as Java 9 having released new `Stream` methods (`takeWhile`, `dropWhile`, etc.) that might be of use.

Comment: If you're open to using Java 9 features, I don't think Java 8 is relevant.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Can be done with [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)

```
public static List<Integer> getIndexList(String s, char c) {
    return IntStream.range(0, s.length())
                    .filter(index -> s.charAt(index) == c)
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: You can also do it using regular Stream, but it involves effectively final class field that would represent current index.

Answer (score 7):

Using Java 9, you can iteratively search using the last index as the starting point, and stop when no match is found:

```
public static List<Integer> getIndexList(String s, char c) {
    return IntStream.iterate(s.indexOf(c), i -> s.indexOf(c, i + 1))
            .takeWhile(i -> i > -1)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Disclaimer: I didn't test this.

Comment: Though the above runs fine for the sample in the question(tested your code for the same inputs), the `takeWhile` part somewhat itches my eyes.

Answer (score 5):

An alternate in Java9 could be to make use of the [`iterate(int seed, IntPredicate hasNext,IntUnaryOperator next)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntPredicate-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) as follows:-

```
private static List<Integer> getIndexList(String word, char c) {
  return IntStream
          .iterate(word.indexOf(c), index -> index >= 0, index -> word.indexOf(c, index + 1))
          .boxed()
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

...Or in java-9:

```
Stream.of("Hello world!")
            .map(Scanner::new)
            .flatMap(s -> s.findAll("l"))
            .map(mr -> mr.start())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Or `new Scanner("Hello world!").findAll("l").map(MatchResult::start)`.

Comment: @shmosel I wanted to post this one initially, but changed my mind for streamy solution :)

Comment: A little too streamy for my tastes, but +1 for the `findAll()` and `start()` combo.