# How check if char appears in string in ArrayList?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, char, java-stream

I am writing a game of Hangman and I need a method that will check if the letter typed by the player occurs in the word that the computer drew from the ArrayList. Do I need to use a stream for this? I've never used a stream, but this may be the time. For better understanding, I throw in my code. Objects and strings are in Polish. Method I would like to put in the createCipher class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hangman {
    static ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrepareGame pomocnik = new PrepareGame();
        PrepareGame.playerChoice pomocnik2 = new PrepareGame.playerChoice();
        words.add("Puszka");
        words.add("Kot");
        words.add("Pies");

        pomocnik.drawWord();
        pomocnik.countLetters();
        pomocnik.createCipher();
        pomocnik2.choose();
    }
}

class PrepareGame {
    playerChoice player = new playerChoice();
    String randomWords;

    void drawWord() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int randomitem = r.nextInt(Hangman.words.size());
        String randomW = Hangman.words.get(randomitem);
        randomWords = randomW;
        System.out.println(randomW);
    }

    void countLetters() {
        int len = randomWords.length();
        System.out.println(len);
    }

    void createCipher() {
            for (int cypher = 0; cypher < randomWords.length(); cypher++) {
                System.out.print("_");
            }
    }

    static class playerChoice {
        ArrayList<String> selectedLetter = new ArrayList<>();
        String choice;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        void choose() {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("wpisz litere: ");
            String pChoice = scan.nextLine();
            choice = pChoice;
            selectedLetter.add(choice);
            System.out.println("Wybrana litera: " + choice);

        }
    }
}
```

I tried with indexOf() and contains() but not worked. Maybe I'm using it wrong.

Comment: You don't need the list with all words for that. You have the drawn word in a variable - `randomWords `, just use indexOf on it.

Comment: Streams are not really what you're looking for as you want indexes, and streams are not really good at those. Scan the 'answer' against the user's choice and add to a `List` the indices where the player was correct. You can then reveal the correct letter at those indices

Comment: It seems correct, so far.  Now check _randomWords_ against _pChoice_.  Start with the _contains_ method, and if _true_, traverse each letter to find the indices.

Comment: That would then be a *double* iteration potentially. Only *one* needed

Comment: Possibly of interest: [A brief hangman implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22269413/256196)

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Do I need to use a stream for this? ..."*

No, you can use the either the *[String#contains](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))*, or *[String#indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int))*, method, to determine if a *String* contains a specific character.

```java
boolean found = randomWords.contains(choice);
```

```java
boolean found = randomWords.indexOf(choice) != -1;
```

Also, for this game, you're going to want to determine all of the indices for a specific letter.

```java
List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();
int index = 0;
char selectedChar = choice.charAt(0);
for (char character : randomWords.toCharArray()) {
    if (character == selectedChar) indices.add(index);
    index++;
}
```

So, if your word is *"Java"*, and *choice* is *"a"*, the *indices* list will contain, *1* and *3*.

> *"... I've never used a stream, but this may be the time. ..."*

Yeah, that is a great approach—there is no better way to learn it, than to simply apply it.

If you're unfamiliar with the topic, there is a great book by O'Reilly Media, which covers the topic in total.
*[O'Reilly Media – Java 8 Lambdas](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-8-lambdas/9781449370831/)*.

There is most likely more than one way to construct this stream.

I'm using the *[String#chars](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#chars())* method to return an *[IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)* object.
From there, I'm utilizing the *[IntStream#anyMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.IntPredicate))* method, with a boolean predicate, to evaluate the character.

```java
char selectedChar = choice.charAt(0);
boolean found
    = randomWords.chars()
                 .anyMatch(character -> character == selectedChar);
```

Using a stream to map the indices is a bit trickier, I had to look it up.
*[StackOverflow – Java 8/9: Can a character in a String be mapped to its indices (using streams)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48592303/17758716)*.

The starting point is a range of *Integer* values, from *0* to the length of *String*.
From there, they stream the range, and only add a character when it matches.

Here's an implementation.
It utilizes the *[range](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range(int,int))*, *[filter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#filter(java.util.function.IntPredicate))*, and *[boxed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed())* methods, of the *IntStream* class, and additionally the *[Stream#toList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList())* method.

```java
char selectedChar = choice.charAt(0);
List<Integer> indices
    = IntStream.range(0, randomWords.length())
               .filter(value -> randomWords.charAt(value) == selectedChar)
               .boxed()
               .toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void createCipher() {
randomWords.chars()
        .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
        .forEach(letter -> {
            if (player.selectedLetter.contains(String.valueOf(letter))) {
                System.out.print(letter);
            } else {
                System.out.print("_");
            }
        });}
```